# WCF security issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate, wcf-security

Some background:
in order to provide authentication I'm using certificates on client and server side (WCF) and use one certificate for all clients (manually loading it from application directory - not the safest way, but it doesn't require to manage certificate storage and making installation more difficult):

```
        AddressHeader hostHdr = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(ServiceFactory.CLIENT_HOST_HEADER, ServiceFactory.NAMESPACE, hostName);
        builder.Headers.Add(hostHdr);
        builder.Identity = new X509CertificateEndpointIdentity(GetServiceCertificate(name));
        

        _factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(name, builder.ToEndpointAddress());
        _factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetClientCertificate(name);
        X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication auth = _factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication;

        auth.CertificateValidationMode =X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
        auth.CustomCertificateValidator = new CustomCertificateValidator(new[] {GetServiceCertificate(name)});
```

This is client side, and serverside host setting up looks like this:

```
private void CertificateSetup(ServiceHost host)
    {
        if (ServiceCertificate != null)
            host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = ServiceCertificate;

        X509ClientCertificateAuthentication authentication =
                        host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication;
        
        authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
            X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;

        authentication.CustomCertificateValidator =
            new CustomCertificateValidator(new [] {ClientCertificate});
    }
```

That works fine and allows to sign messages, but as far as security mode set in following way:

```
      <security mode="Message">            
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
```

But i need

```
string name = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
```

somehow to obtain WindowsIdentity in ServiceSecurityContext.
Mixed (Transport and Message) security mode is not helpful, because I don't know why but even if i set Windows clientCredentials in config for Transport part mode  infrastructure tries to establish SSL connection.

Any ideas ????

---

Certificates are used for message signing,i.e. proving that other side is either real client or service (man-in-the-middle). But authorization in system being developed partially relies on WindowsIdentity in ServiceSecurityContect. All i want-include WindowsIdentity in sec.context, meanwhile PrimaryIdentity is X509CertIdentity.
So i need to know on serverside which domain user requested service operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link re: Impersonation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx

section on - "Mapping a Client Certificate to a Windows Account", seems like what you're after.

with config on client:

```
authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true"
```

Client code:

' Create a binding that sets a certificate as the client credential type.

```
Dim b As WSHttpBinding = New WSHttpBinding()

b.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate
```

' Create a service host that maps the certificate to a Windows account.

```
Dim httpUri As Uri = New Uri("http://localhost/Calculator")

Dim sh As ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(HelloService), httpUri)

sh.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.MapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount = True
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, WCF can be painful at times!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using message security with certificates at each end securing it, I'm not quite sure why you would need a windows identity? What's the reasoning behind that?

Maybe this link will be of use - sections 6 & 7 have details of config settings for certificate authentiaction, which works similarly to SSL:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcf_certificates.aspx

Comment: Certificates are used for message signing,i.e. proving that other side is either real client/service.But authorization partially relies on WindowsIdentity in ServiceSecurityContect. All i want-include WindowsIdentity in sec.context, meanwhile PrimaryIdentity is X509CertIdentity.

Comment: So i need to know on serverside which domain user requested service operation.